# jQuery onclick event is not triggered inside bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this bootstrap carousel and i want to catch the click event on a image inside it in order to open a self made lightbox when clicked on a image inside the carousel, but the javascript code doesn't trigger with this syntax for some unknown reason:

```
$('html').on("click", ".lightbox-content img", function () {
  console.log("i'm NOT triggered!");
});
```

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="table-cell lightbox-content">
    <div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel small-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/office-space1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/office-space2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/office-space3.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Bootstrap/jQuery is working correctly on other parts of the site.
I'm using jquery-1.11.3.min.js and Bootstrap v3.3.5.

Comment: Try `$(document).on("click", ".lightbox-content img", function () {`

Comment: @Tushar shouldn't make any difference

Comment: Both seem to be working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/73d4w141/). Anything missing in the question?

Comment: @IBadarau Sounds like click event propagation is stopped in some way, try firstly to delegate event to `#myCarousel1` level. BTW, do you really need to delegate event?

Comment: @A.Wolff look at the answer from OP, WOT 0_0

Comment: @Tushar haha, i'm glad he has found his issue  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.lightbox-content img').click(function () {
    console.log("i'm NOT triggered!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change the JS to:

```
$('.lightbox-content img').click(function () {
  alert("i'm triggered!");
});
```

check this pen:
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyQyOE)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
   $(document).on("click", ".lightbox-content img", function () {
  console.log("i'm triggered!");
  });
```

When using .on() JQuery is looking inside your document for an event. This is also used if you reload your paging using jquery and you want the javascript functions to keep running

Answer (score 0):

Sry for the misleading. It was a css problem. For some reason someone put

```
z-index: -1;
```

to .carousel-inner class. Now is working properly

Comment: Worth noting point here is to add _complete_ and _relevant_ code in question and if possible adding live demo to get answer. Check [mcve].